# Why gooey effect doesn't work with canvas particles?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

Something wrong, but I don't understand what exacly. It works well with div elements, but ignores particles in canvas.

```
<svg>
        <defs>
            <filter id="goo">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur" />
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix" 
                   values=" 1 0 0 0 0
                            0 1 0 0 0
                            0 0 1 0 0
                            0 0 0 22 -9" />
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blur" ></feBlend>
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

[full demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/Vladasha/pen/poEpMpM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved**.
It doesn't work because of the background on the canvas.

```
canvas {background: #ffffff; }
```